# PostgreSQL UUID Literal: ERROR: syntax error at or near

Tags: postgresql, syntax, uuid

Whever I use a UUID as a literal, I get

```
SELECT a82857b6-e336-4c6c-8499;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
```

I thought it might be an encoding issue, but that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS), string constants (or in general: anything that is not a number) need to be enclosed in single quotes:

```
ALTER TABLE newarts ALTER COLUMN jurisdiction_id 
   SET DEFAULT 'a82857b6-e336-4c6c-8499-4242';
```

Comment: OF COURSE! But that's why sometimes I need another pair of eyes. It is more like a string than an integer. I just didn't see / think of it. Thanks.